# Slope of a vertical line

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the equation of the line that satisfies the given conditions:

Through $(-1,2)$; parallel to the line $x=5$

I know that the equation  of this line is $x=-1$ because $x=5$ is a vertical line and any line parallel to it would be vertical as well. So the line runs vertically along $x=-1$.

But how would I solve this algebraically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasoning you gave in your question **is** algebraic: I see nothing wrong with it. You can't use the standard "parallel lines have equal slopes" since your lines have undefined slopes.

---

However, here is another approach. All lines can be put in general linear form:

$$Ax+By=E$$

You first find $A$, $B$, and $E$ (non-unique) for your starting line $x=5$. You want to find another line,

$$Cx+Dy=F$$

that is parallel to your line, which happens when

$$AD-BC=0$$

Find $C$ and $D$ that fulfill that requirement, and find $F$ so that the point $(-1,2)$ is on the line. Then you are done!

---

If you want still another, slightly different approach, you could use the form

$$x \cdot \cos \theta + y \cdot \sin \theta = r$$

where $\theta$ is the direction angle of a vector perpendicular to the line and $r$ is the distance of the origin from the line. Two lines are parallel if their $\theta$'s are equal or differ by a multiple of $\pi$. In your particular problem, $\theta$ is zero.

Comment: I know that for a horizontal line, the equation of the line in slope-intercept form would be $y=0x+b$ What is the equation of a vertical line? Since the slope is undefined.

Comment: There is *no* equation in slope-intercept form ($y=mx+b$) for a vertical line, since that form requires a slope ($m$) and a vertical does not have a slope. That is why I used two other forms of a line, both of which can handle vertical lines. Many Algebra 1 textbooks use the form $x=a$ for vertical lines, which works *only* for vertical lines.

Comment: What would $x=6$ look like in the general equation of a line then?

Comment: @Cherry_Developer: There are infinitely many answers to that, but one is $1 \cdot x + 0 \cdot y = 6$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the line$$x=5$$
$$0=x-5$$
$$0y=x-5$$
$$y=\frac{x}{0}-\frac{5}{0}$$
$$y=\infty x-5\infty$$
Now try to determine the slope of a line perpendicular to this line.
$$m_\perp = -\frac{1}{m}=-\frac{1}{\infty}=0$$
Then try to find a line that passes through $(-1,2)$ with a slope of $m_\perp=0$
$$m_\perp=0=\frac{y-2}{x+1}$$
$$0(x+1)=y-2$$
$$y-2=0$$
$$y=2$$
$$y=0x+2$$
Now consider a line that passes through (-1,2) of the form 
$$y=ax+b$$
where $a$ is non-zero. The slope of a line that is perpendicular to this line has a slope of $-1/a\ne 0$, therefore, this line cannot be perpendicular to $y=0x+2$. If $a=0$, then the 2 lines coincide (and a line is parallel to itself, and therefore not perpendicular to itself). So we can conclude that the line is not of this form $y=ax+b$.

The only other form of line is modeled with the equation
$$x=b$$
substituting we have
$$-1 = b$$
and so, the line is
$$x=-1$$